# OD Cost Matrix Solver Failed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, accessibility, arcgis-10.6

I am doing accessibility analysis. I created network dataset in ArcMap 10.6
I made a fishnet and I typed 100 and 100 for cell width and height, leaving rows and columns blank. I continue with OD Cost Matrix. I can create origins and destinations. When I click solve in network analyst, after 20 minutes or more, solver fails. This happens right after writing lines. Some of you might say it could be RAM problem. My computer's RAM is 16 GB. Interesting enough, when I choose cell width and height as 500 in fishnet, I can't see any problem, it works fine. But I need to create cell width and height of the fishnet as 100. Size of the area is 604161642.987255 (shape_area).

What should I do?

I am new to network analysis therefore accessibility.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. A 100x100 fishnet is 25 times larger than a 500x500. Please [edit] the question to specify the size of the study area.